# question about a particular Polynomial ring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, fields

Let K be a field, let $T = K[X_1, X_2,...]$ be a polynomial ring, let $R=K[X_1^{2}, X_1X_2,..,X_i X_j,..]$, and let $L = Frac(R)$ = field of fractions of R. How can we prove that $R =T \cap L$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the involution $\sigma $ of $T$ which maps each $X_i$ to $-X_i$; the $\sigma $-invariant subring of  $T$ is $R$. Similarly $\sigma $ extends to the field of fractions $E$ of $T$, and the $\sigma $-invariant subfield of $T$ is $L$. Thus $T\cap L=T\cap E^{\sigma }=T^{\sigma }=R$.